# MacOS App proc_listpids() fails, but works on other program

Tags: macos, darwin

I am new to MacOS and especially its lower level stuff, I built a CLI program to inject a dylib into a vulnrable process. It works fine, but I wanted to make a GUI program to do this, but now on my call to

`proc_listallpids(NULL, 0);`

the return value is always 0. Looking into some source code I found:

```
if ((error = proc_security_policy(PROC_NULL, PROC_INFO_CALL_LISTPIDS, type, NO_CHECK_SAME_USER)))
        return (error);
```

But I was not able to find the source code for this function to find out why it fails(assuming this is the reason it does fail)

Is proc_listallpids() not allowed to be called from Apps? If so is there a way I can still make a GUI program but use this function? I was kind of thinking this might be to do with restrictions for the appstore but I wouldn't want my program on the appstore

Also I was wondering if there is a better site to go for topics like this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was App Sandbox, not sure if this is worth keeping around or not. I turned it off in the project settings and the function works now